# iPhone Core Data - Issues with NSNumber and obj_exception_throw

Tags: cocoa-touch, debugging, ios, core-data

Oh Im really in a pickle on this one. Maybe your fresh eyes can do some magic..

My app is crashing when it get's to this line in viewDidLoad.

```
NSString *fieldName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"position%d", [objectPosition intValue]];
```

I think it might be due to this line which is above it:

```
    NSNumber *objectPosition  = [[object position] integerValue];
```

There is no explicit error on the fieldName line.

General warnings include:

- Initialization makes pointer from integer without a cast
- 'NSManagedObject' may not respond to '-position'
- obj_exception_throw

I checked the class for [object position] and it says it's actually a NSCFNumber.
Am I doing something wrong with NSNumber? Where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Evolve

The whole method is listed here, here also is a link to the whole file https://gist.github.com/801879

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  // Format page
  scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(200, 430);

  // Initialise PositionsView array
  positionViews = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:position1,position2,position3,position4,position5,position6,position7,position8,position9,position10,position11,position12,position13,position14,position15,position16,position17,position18,nil];

  // Load managedObject
  //Fetch All players from PlayerPosition where game matches this game and store in objects
  NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
  NSEntityDescription *entityDescription = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PlayerPosition" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext_];  
  [request setEntity:entityDescription];  
  NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(game = %@)", self.game];   //WHERE game = self.game
  [request setPredicate:pred];
  NSError *error;
  objects = [managedObjectContext_ executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]; //execute fetch and store in objects


  NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    Populate View with data from the managedObject..    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");

  for (NSManagedObject *object in objects) {
    //loop through the objects in PlayerPosition for this game and update UI elements.
    Player   *objectPlayer    = [object valueForKey:@"player"];

    NSNumber *objectPosition  = [[object position] integerValue];
    NSLog(@"Object: %@", [object valueForKey:@"position"]);
    NSString *fieldName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"position%d", [objectPosition intValue]];
    PlayerPositionView *theField = [self valueForKey:fieldName];
    [[theField textLabel] setText:objectPlayer.playerShortName];
    NSLog(@"object Position: %@", [objectPosition description]);

  }
  NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>    ..view Data Loaded    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<");

  [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[[object position] integerValue]` will return an `NSInteger`, not an `NSNumber *`. Since the return value is not an object, you can't (and needn't to) send it an `-intValue` message. Just use the `NSInteger` value directly in `+stringWithFormat:`.

Comment: Ive change that. I think that has helped a little.  I can get to this page now in my app without it crashing, once I add a record and exit and attempt to come back, it complains of the same line with the message 'Unable to access variable "fieldName" and crashes'